# Qlikview - text object num

Tags: qlikview

I have text object with text

```
=num( Sum( Aggr( Quantity*Price, PostingYear1, LineNumber )), '#,##0.0')
```

and I have year 2015 and 2016.
When save this expresions i got sum of bouth year 2015 and 2016. how to get only 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use set analysis:

```
=num( Sum({<Year = {2015}>} Aggr( Quantity*Price, PostingYear1, LineNumber )), '#,##0.0')
```

Comment: insted 5000 i got 4 937, what can be problem